# project crystal report for vs 2010 does not work in windows any 7 32 bit or 64 bit

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

My project crystal report  for vs 2010 nicely works in windows xp but when I setup it in windows 7 or 10 it does not work any 32 or 64 bit windows. I used datatable in crystal report. I discussed with many big programmers they suggest me about add some dll in project or use dataset. but it does not work also. same problem.

in loading crystal report with dataset or dataTable. In this section `tyu.SetDataSource(ds);` does not load data. or .rpt error 17

I use SQL Server in database and c# windows application.

What I have tried:

```
private void PrintRep()
{

     //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     //string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn_str"].ConnectionString;
     SqlDataAdapter dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  dbo.T_ATTR  Order by dbo.T_ATTR.IndRegID ", "Data Source=DESKTOP-IRFOPKM\\SHUVO;Initial Catalog=ServiceOneEasyClock;User ID=sa;Password=S123456_");
     DataSet dset = new DataSet();
     dadapter.Fill(dset, "dbo.T_ATTR");
     int op = 0;
     op= 1;
     frmReportsViewer rptviewer = new frmReportsViewer(op, dset);
     rptviewer.Show();
}

private void frmReportsViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (option == 1)
      {
          try
          {   //ParameterFields pfs = new ParameterFields();
              //pfs = GetCompanyInformation();
              //crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = pfs;
              string username = "sa"; // database user name
              string password = "S123456_"; //database password



              ds.AcceptChanges();
              tyu.Refresh();
              ////tyu.Refresh();
              //tyu.Refresh();
              try
              {
                  tyu.SetDataSource(ds);
              }

              catch(Exception ex)

              {
                  MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
              }
              crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = tyu;
              crystalReportViewer.RefreshReport();
              crystalReportViewer.Show();

          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
          }
      }

      if (option == 2)
      {
          try
          {   //ParameterFields pfs = new ParameterFields();
              //pfs = GetCompanyInformation();
              //crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = pfs;
              oRpt2.SetDataSource(dtr);
              crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = oRpt2;
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: sir, Problem in loading crystal report with dataset or dataTable. In this section  tyu.SetDataSource(ds); does not loading data. or .rpt error...error 17

Answer (score 0):

if you get this error:

```
Failed to open the connection. Details: [Database Vendor Code: 17 ]
Failed to open the connection. C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\{ADB8090C-40ED-499D-88E3-915E23B0C5C3}.rpt 
Details: [Database Vendor Code: 17 ]
```

Do the following steps:

1. Open the report in the CR XI designer.
2. Select Database -> Set Datasource Location.
3. Set Datasource Location window will appear and in the replace with section connect to the database and replace these tables with the tables in the current datasource by clicking the update button.
4. After updating close the Set Datasource Location window.
5. Go to 'Database menu' and Click 'Verify Database' and click on ’OK’.
6. Preview the report and the save the report.
   ;)

Comment: not working code. no error now but crystal report is not loading.

Comment: I googled and doing every thing but not founding any error so I can't finding any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Crystal Reports Runtime for VS 2010 on the Windows 7 machine?

[Deploying Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 Runtime](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Deploying+Crystal+Reports+for+Visual+Studio+2010+Runtime)

I've had to do this when moving my project from my dev machine to a production one.